# How to change metallic smoothness using .mtl file

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, mtl-file

I am trying to change the material type of an `.obj` file in Unity's Stander Shader. I also try to change the `metallic smoothness` using a `.mtl` file but I am unable to do so.

How can I do that?

My current `.mtl` file:

```
newmtl wire_176026026
Ka 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
Kd 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
illum 2
Ns 1000

map_Kd 2013112203271069358.jpg
map_bump 20131121101217386434.jpg
bump 20131121101217386434.jpg
```

Comment: Please try removing one by one the `.jpg` lines, other settings don't affect the visual effect you mentioned.

Comment: its texture and normal map, that required!!, but I know reflect effect on smoothness but how I don't know.